# GeckoDriver support for protractor to execute latest FF versions

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium3

As we know, `Selenium Webdriver 2.53.1` is limited to `Firefox browser 45/46` and its below versions.

Selenium 3 was launched by removing entire `Selenium RC Core` along with additional support on latest browsers recently. It uses GeckoDriver to drive the latest Firefox browsers.

However, is there any implementation of Protractor to support the latest Selenium 3 and GeckoDriver driven tests to handle latest FF versions.

[image]

Does Protractor tests are limited to FF45, FF46?

When I launch `firefox 48.0.1` with `Selenium 2.53.1` through `browser.get("http://example.com")`, the browser is opened as usual but not the url as shown below,

```
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox',
  },
```

[image]

Note: As far as I know, the latest Firefox versions have inbuilt algorithms to handle GeckoDriver and selenium 3 APIs, cos, the FF terms are made strict to avoid external breaches. FF 47+ versions are Gecko-based browsers.

Comment: @lauda It's about Protractor on Selenium 3 to overcome latest FF browsers